# Azure AD B2C Custom policy language translation

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have declared a set of supported langauges in my custom policy.
But what happens is, Microsoft implicitly convert some text and messages to other languages eventhough when i haven't decalred that langugae to be supportred.

(Eg) I haven't supported croatian language in my app, so when i pass croatian langauge in my query param, it should point to default language referred in the custom policy, Because croatian is in my unsupported langugaes list. what in reality some of the messages gets converted to croatian and shown in UI.

Answer (score 1):

It is true. And Custom Policies out of the box supported language customization but support is limited to few fields/inputs/labels/messages. If your application support multi language then you can add your own customization.

> (Eg) I haven't supported croatian language in my app, so when i pass croatian langauge in my query param, it should point to default language referred in the custom policy, Because croatian is in my unsupported langugaes list. what in reality some of the messages gets converted to croatian and shown in UI.

Update: Currently this is not possible and you need to limit supported languages from your application it self.

**Typical Multi Language Scenario for a web/ native application (may be a workaround):**

1. Web application show up the list of supported languages either in drop down or any user friendly way
2. Application will capture the locale from the customer selected language and append to the request URL.
3. If that locale is valid at B2C side it will start displaying Ux in that language

There is only 1% changes where customers can actually edit the Authorize URL to modify the locale. **Your concern is still valid** but based on above scenario itwill become less impact on your application.

Comment: Its fine. But we cannot go for a workaround at this stage, because the mobile app is already in production and millions of users as the customer base.We cannot change the language in the query param, because when the user selects the croatia country, by default the mobile app will be sending croatian language, but i have defined supported languages in my custom policy which does not have croatian language and hence it should show default language(Englih).

Comment: I don't mean to say mine is workaround. That is how all the applications should work (includes yours).  Users never edit authorize URLs. So even B2C supports all the languages, you can still limit your languages from your Application (ex: Show your application supported languages in the drop down)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to force the locale you can use the query string when requesting the B2C application.

```
?ui_locales={en}
```

Where you would replace `{en}` with the locale you support for more info see the [offical docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-language-customization)